# Cypher WITH aggregation in query

Tags: filtering, neo4j, aggregation, cypher

I have a Cypher Query question related to filtering mechanism implementation.

Let's assume we are performing a filter to **PROFILE** nodes.. for simplicity there are two types of filters **F1** ,**F2**.
Each filter requires a separated **MATCH** clause in the query.

I need to retrieve **PROFILES** where (**F1** or **F2**) = true sorted by date.
So at first I thought of something like the following:

```
START(node) match (Applying F1 filter)->profile WITH profile,node
            match (Applying F2 filter)->profile2
```

But now I need to apply the return clause with order by ..

Is there a way to aggregate the profiles from previous match without override them? something like..

```
START(node) match (Applying F1 filter)->profile WITH profile,node
            match (Applying F2 filter)->profile return profile order by profile.date
```

Help will be appreciated
 Thanks

Comment: you mean something like an union?

Comment: yep that's correct..any way to do that? or maybe workaround on the WITH ?

Comment: Now i see found the union function... but can i order by the union?